# Unable to authenticate mongo user created with docker env variables

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm using the official [mongodb docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) with docker-compose.
But I'm unable to authenticate using the environment variables `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME`, `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD`.
In docker-compose.yaml:

```
mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepass
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: somedb
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - backend-network
```

After running the container, I failed to authenticate:

```
$ docker exec -it mongo mongo -u root -p somepass --authenticationDatabase somedb
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=somedb&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

I can't figure what I'm doing wrong.
It looks like this user was not even created:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-10T11:23:05.772+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ACCESS",   "id":20249,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Authentication failed","attr":{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","principalName":"root","authenticationDatabase":"somedb","client":"127.0.0.1:50990","result":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"root\" for db \"somedb\""}}
```

I've also tried to:

- Remove the env variable `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` and to authenticate against "admin" db.
- Created an additional user with `db.createUser()` in a js file that I've put in the container in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`, then tried to authenticate with this user.

I got the same error message in both cases.

**EDIT:**
When I'm not bind-mount to `/data/db`, it works

Answer (score 2):

You should authenticate using `authenticationDatabase admin`.

From the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo):

> MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME, MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD These
> variables, used in conjunction, create a new user and set that user's
> password. This user is created in the admin authentication database
> and given the role of root, which is a "superuser" role.

`docker exec -it mongo mongo -u root -p somepass --authenticationDatabase admin`

should work.

Sequence that worked:

- Created the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

  ```
   mongo:
        image: mongo:4.4
        container_name: mongo
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        environment:
          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
          MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: somepass
          MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: somedb
          SERVICE_TAGS: dev
          SERVICE_NAME: mongo
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
  ```
- Ran `docker-compose up -d` in the folder where `docker-compose.yaml` is located
- Logged in to mongo shell: `docker exec -it mongo mongo -u root -p somepass --authenticationDatabase admin`

Comment: I still get the same error. It works only if I remove the `volumes` section from docker-compose.yaml, have no idea why

Comment: it worked for me once `network` section is removed as i don't have such a network. `mongodata` is named volume, it probably contains data already and `docker-compose up` probably fails when you run it. I've updated my answer with sequence of commands which should work, i'd suggest overcome the authentication issue after successfull `docker-compose up` and then add network and volumes.

Comment: when you remove `volumes` section, `mongodb` is storing data inside the container and it starts with empty data, so it may explain why you succeed. When you use named volume `mongodbdata`, it may already contain data (including username and password of admin database. You should also remove `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE`  env. variable unless you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I know the issue is old, but I just had the same thing happen to me. What happened to me was, I accidentally used the wrong environment variables for MongoDB init, so it never created a user (mongo/mongo in my case).

And me using the `volumes` just like you means that whatever I did (except removing the `volumes` from the *docker-compose.yml*, same as you), it never got to connect correctly with my specified username and password.

*What you need to do, and anyone else with this issue is, **delete** the volume on your host machine, so it will be recreated with the new environment data from the docker compose file.*

So in your case, all you needed to do was delete the **mongodbdata** folder and/or contents of it, so the next time your run your compose, it will re-init the DB with new data :).

So in the end, in addition to using `authSource=admin` or `--authenticationDatabase admin`, I had to do this as well.

Hope this saves time for anyone else having this issue, I just lost 2 hours of my life on a silly issue :).